# LTE network open for all users (no AKA procedure)

Tags: authentication, mobile, lte, 4g

I was wondering if there is some way a LTE network can operate in a way that it allows any user to connect to it without having to be registered on its HSS database.

I know the normal mode of operation is to perform the AKA procedure that relies on both the HSS and the uSIM on the UE to know the values of K and OP, so that both the UE and the HSS can authenticate each other. I am also aware of the special case of an emergency registration procedure, where the network allows an user to make emergency calls regardless of whether they have a SIM on their phone or not.

There definitely would be some use cases that would benefit from the ability to put a WiFi-like hotspot that everyone could access, leaving aside the security risks that this would entail.